# How to make stdin file descriptor ready when pressing a key?

Tags: c, linux, select, stdin

I have a custom _kbhit() function used for non-blocking character input.
_kbhit() function uses select() to check if stdin is ready to read.
But finally I have stdin ready if only I pressed RETURN.
How to make it work when I press any key?

```
void set_conio_terminal_mode()
{
    struct termios new_termios;

    /* take two copies - one for now, one for later */
    tcgetattr(0, &new_termios);

    /* register cleanup handler, and set the new terminal mode */
    atexit(reset_terminal_mode);
    cfmakeraw(&new_termios);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios);
}

int _kbhit()
{
    struct timeval tv = { 0L, 0L };
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    return select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
}

static char _getch(void) {
    int r;
    unsigned char c;
    if ((r = read(0, &c, sizeof(c))) < 0) {
        return r;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    set_conio_terminal_mode();
    while (1) {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            inputbuffer[inputlen] = _getch();
            if (inputbuffer[inputlen] >= 0x20 && inputbuffer[inputlen] < 0x7F) {
                putchar(inputbuffer[inputlen]);
                inputlen++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that this code will output echo, but it outputs entire string just after I press RETURN.

Comment: I was very close to solution. But I thought its the buffering in stdin, but the problem is the buffering in stdout.

Comment: function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `unsigned char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that - despite your initialization of the terminal attributes using `cfmakeraw()` - `stdout` is still in line-buffered mode.

Try setting standard output to unbuffered mode.

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

which is equivalent to

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This avoids the need to call `fflush(stdout);` after every `putchar(inputbuffer[inputlen]);`.

There may be a way of accomplishing this using `tcsetattr()` instead of `setvbuf()`, buf I am not familiar with it.